# Polymer: Access dynamically created node of dynamically created custom element

Tags: polymer, shadow-dom, polymer-2.x

While updating my polymer project from 1.x to 2.0 I encountered this problem

I am wrapping one of my custom elements in dom-repeat like this

**Host**

```
<dom-repeat items="{{customer.hubs}}" as="item">
      <template>
        <paper-card elevation="2" class="hubCard">
          <div style="font-size: 25px;font-weight: bold;line-height: 48px">HUB [[printIndex(customer.hubs,index)]]</div>
          <hub-info hub="{{item}}" isloading="{{isloading}}" refresh-customer="[[refreshCustomer]]"/>
        </paper-card>
      </template>
    </dom-repeat>
```

part of the code of custom element is like below

**Custom element**

```
<div class="blueButton" id="debugTab" style="padding-top: 10px">
  <dom-if if="{{displayDebugger}}">
  <template>
    <div class="headButton" on-click="toggleDebugger" id="debuggerTab">
     <span>Debugger</span>
      <span style="position: absolute;right: 2%">
    <!--<i id="downArrow4" class="material-icons fa-arrow-down">keyboard_arrow_down</i>-->
    <iron-icon id="downArrow4" icon="icons:arrow-drop-down"></iron-icon>
      </span>
      </div>
</template>
  </dom-if>
<iron-collapse id="collapseDebugger" >
<hub-debugger hub-id="{{hub.hubId}}" isloading="{{isloading}}"></hub-debugger>
</iron-collapse>
  </div>
```

**Problem**

First i tried to access iron-collapse as
this.$.collapseDebugger but i couldn't ,as i thought the custom elemrnt hub-info is inside dom-repeat i used this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#collapseDebugger') and accessed it.
Again i tried to access iron-icon (which is again dynamically created inside dom-if) as this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#downArrow4') but i am unable to access it.

*How to access a dynamic node inside dynamic element?
 What if there is nesting of dynamic creations?*

Answer (score 0):

The `this.shadowRoot.querySelector(selector)` syntax should work.

Is the conditional template actually rendered? Do you  import `polymer/lib/elements/dom-if.html` in your custom element? This is needed, if you otherwise only import `polymer/polymer-element.html`.

Comment: Yes,Conditional template is rendered and I imported both polymer-element.html and dom-if.html.

Comment: Strange. It works on my side. Another thing I can think of is that you are trying to access the element too early. But if it worked alright in Polymer 1, then I'm not sure.

Comment: Not only this case, even in few other custom elements of my project instead of this.$.id selector this.shadowRoot.querySelector(selector) is only working. Am i missing anything?